# Javascript Rollover Image Link

Tags: javascript, image, swap, rollover

I really hope that one of you JS Gurus can shed light on this problem.

Currently I'm working on a webpage that has small table with 5 text lines in column one.
And an image in column two.

The client is asking for the following:

1. open the page, the "default image" should show
2. roll-on the text, the "temp image" should show
3. roll-off the text, the "default image" should show
4. click on the text, that temp image should become the "default
   image"

I was able to achieve objectives #1, #2, and #3.
However, to be able to achieve #4, the client's old code simply made identical pages, each with a different "default image". And assigned each link to point to that page.

Is it possible to achieve objective #4 without having to make duplicate pages?
Maybe, there could be a javascript code that refreshes the page, and alters the default image according to the link (text) clicked?

Am I even making any sense? Sorry, I've hardly ever used forums. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct etiquette's here.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeIt(imageName,objName)
{
var obj = document.getElementById(objName);
var imgTag = "<img src=' "+imageName+" ' border='0' height='207' width='400'/>";
obj.innerHTML = imgTag;
return;
}
</script>
<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="6">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="33%" valign="top" nowrap><span style="font-size: 12pt;"> <a id="one" href="#"
                OnMouseOver="changeIt('/images/stories/article/compressor_experience.jpg','image1');"
                onClick="changeIt('/images/stories/article/compressor_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                OnMouseOut="changeIt('/images/stories/article/composite_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                style="text-decoration: none;"><strong>Compressor Stations</strong></a></span></td>
                <td valign="top" nowrap><strong>4,000,000 hp</strong> </td><td rowspan="5" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                <td rowspan="5" valign="top">
                    <div id="image1"><img src="images/stories/article/composite_experience.jpg" alt="one" border="0" height="207" width="400" /></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="33%" valign="top" nowrap style="border-top:1px solid #bbb;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><a id="two" href="#" 
                OnMouseOver="changeIt('/images/stories/article/export_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                onClick="changeIt('/images/stories/article/export_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                OnMouseOut="changeIt('/images/stories/article/composite_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                style="text-decoration: none;"><strong>Export, Storage, and<br />Loading Systems</strong></a></span> </td>
                <td valign="top" nowrap style="border-top:1px solid #bbb;"><strong>1,000,000,000 bbls</strong> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="33%" valign="top" nowrap style="border-top:1px solid #bbb;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><a id="three" href="#" 
                OnMouseOver="changeIt('/images/stories/article/pipeline_experience.jpg','image1');"  
                onClick="changeIt('/images/stories/article/pipeline_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                OnMouseOut="changeIt('/images/stories/article/composite_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                style="text-decoration: none;"><strong>Pipeline Systems</strong></a></span> </td>
                <td valign="top" nowrap style="border-top:1px solid #bbb;"><strong>100,000 miles</strong> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="33%" valign="top" nowrap style="border-top:1px solid #bbb;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><a id="four" href="#" 
                OnMouseOver="changeIt('/images/stories/article/production_experience.jpg','image1');"
                OnMouseOut="changeIt('/images/stories/article/composite_experience.jpg','image1');"                 
                onClick="changeIt('/images/stories/article/production_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                style="text-decoration: none;"><strong>Production and<br />Processing Facilities</strong></a></span> </td>
                <td valign="top" nowrap style="border-top:1px solid #bbb;"><strong>2,000,000 bpd</strong> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="33%" valign="top" nowrap style="border-top:1px solid #bbb;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><a id="five" href="#" 
                OnMouseOver="changeIt('/images/stories/article/pump_experience.jpg','image1');"  
                onClick="changeIt('/images/stories/article/pump_experience.jpg','image1');"
                OnMouseOut="changeIt('/images/stories/article/composite_experience.jpg','image1');" 
                style="text-decoration: none;"><strong>Pump Stations</strong></a></span> </td>
                <td valign="top" nowrap style="border-top:1px solid #bbb;"><strong>300,000 hp</strong> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thank you all in advance.